# Separar cadena y llenar columnas con sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy trabajando con cadenas de texto que están almacenadas en una tabla, pero debo extraer algunos datos para unas consultas.
Por ahora tengo esto:

```
---------------------------------
archivo         |Folio    |Fecha|
T_0203_20200908 |T        |     |
T_0203_20200908 |0203     |     |
T_0203_20200908 |20200908 |     |
```

Ya me separa los datos por el caracter '_' , pero todos los pone en las misma columna con esto:

```
 SELECT nombre_archivo,
        t.n.value('.','CHAR(100)') as Data
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT nombre_archivo,  
          CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(nombre_archivo, '_', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
        FROM  ArchivosOK
    )  AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS t(n);
```

Y para acomodar los datos en las demás columnas, he tratado lo siguiente:

```
  SELECT nombre_archivo,
            t.n.value('col[2]','CHAR(100)') as Folio
            t.n.value('col[3]','CHAR(100)') as Fecha
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT nombre_archivo,  
              CAST(('<rows><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(nombre_archivo,'_','</col></row><row> 
              <col>'),'_','</col><col>') + '</col></row></rows>') AS XML) As Data
        FROM  ArchivosOK
    )  AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/rows/row') AS t(n);
```

el resultado que espero es :

```
  ---------------------------------
    archivo         |Folio    |Fecha    |
    T_0203_20200908 |0203     |20200908 |
    T_0204_20200909 |0204     |20200908 |
    T_0205_20200906 |0205     |20200906 |
```

pero eso me manda todo null, ¿Me podrían sugerir alguna de forma de hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para extraer segmentos separados por el caracter `'_'` en SQL Server, puedes valerte de las funciones [`charindex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) y [`substring`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql).

Con `charindex` encuentras la posición de cada caracter y con `substring` obtienes las subcadenas delimitadas por estas posiciones.

Aunque se podría escribir todo en una sola sentencia (difícil de leer). Yo sugiero escribir primero un CTE que nos dé las posiciones de los caracteres de interés y finalmente escribir la sentencia que extrae las partes de la cadena, pues esto es más fácil de leer (y de mantener):

Por ejemplo:

```
with
ArchivosOK as (
select *
  from (values ('T_0203_20200908')
             , ('T_0204_20200909')
             , ('T_0205_20200906')
        ) q1 (archivo)
)
,
ArchivoConSeparador as (
select   Archivo 
       , charindex('_', Archivo) Separador1
       , charindex('_', Archivo, charindex('_', Archivo) + 1) Separador2
  from ArchivosOK
)
select  Archivo
      , substring(Archivo, Separador1 + 1, Separador2 - Separador1 - 1) Folio
      , substring(Archivo, Separador2 + 1, 10) Fecha
  from ArchivoConSeparador;
```

Nos dará el resultado que buscas:

```
Archivo         Folio           Fecha
--------------- --------------- ----------
T_0203_20200908 0203            20200908
T_0204_20200909 0204            20200909
T_0205_20200906 0205            20200906

(3 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-10-12T08:33:45.7895890-06:00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado